# How to update FormArray value with variable length

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

If I try to set a FormArray value when the FormArray is empty:

```
const array1 = new FormArray([]);
array1.setValue(['']);
```

I get this error:

> There are no form controls registered with this array yet. If you're using ngModel, you may want to check next tick

If I add 2 when there is 1:

```
const array2 = new FormArray([new FormControl('')]);
array2.setValue(['', '']);
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot find form control at index 1

If I try to set 1 when there are 2:

```
const array3 = new FormArray([new FormControl(''), new FormControl('')]);
array3.setValue(['']);
```

I get the following error:

> Must supply a value for form control at index: 1.

**Question**: How do I write a function which can update the value of a Form Array with a list of arbitrary length?

**StackBlitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wduzv9?file=src/app/app.component.ts

***edit**
I understand that I can use the `push()`, `at()`, and `removeAt(0)` methods. I'm looking for a general-purpose function. It can use any methods you want.

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Chellappan In one case, I'm syncing the value with another control. In the other, inserting default values conditionally to then be updated at the level of the FormControl. Does it matter, though?

Comment: FormArray are index based you should acces using at  method, like this array2.at(0).setValue(['']);

Comment: @Chellappan Yes, I understand and appreciate this fact fully. Do you have an answer?

Comment: try  this array2.reset(['','''])

Comment: @Chellappan That doesn't work. There is no error, but the value is not updated. It seems to suffer the same problem of requiring the controls to exist at those indexes already.

Comment: I forked your example and i can see the updated value check the console:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y2pteg

Comment: @Chellappan Yea, but not solving for variable length. If it already has a value at that index then it works. It doesn't answer the question I asked though.

Comment: @KevinBeal, if you use setValue, you need send as many elements as the formArray.length, else use patchValue. If you want create a formArray from an array, you can use `array=new FormArray(myArray.map(x=>new FormControl(x))`. NOTE: You need import `ReactiveFormsModule` in your app.module.ts. NOTE2: use a ngOnInit, you're declaring the const outside the Component

Comment: @Eliseo You are mistaken about patchValue. It will not add new form controls.

Comment: NO, patchValue only allow send an arbritary quantity of values. If you send less elements than the number of formsControls there are in the array, fill the first elements, if you send more elements, fill the array using the firsts elements, but not increase the length of the FormArray. Sorry if I confused you about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that adding new values at new keys or indexes can't be done without knowing what type of `AbstractControl` you want inside the `FormArray` at the new index.

Any solution must take into account whether that index should be a `FormControl`, `FormGroup`, or `FormArray`, hence the `toSubControl` parameter I offer in my `setFormArrayValue` function. (I also provide some example values to supply to this parameter.)

I opted to remove all items and then add new controls per value. Trying to preserve the controls already there was producing some weird behavior.

This is the solution I came up with:

```
type ControlFactory<T> = (values: T) => AbstractControl;

export function setFormArrayValue<T>(
    array: FormArray,
    values: T[],
    toSubControl: ControlFactory<T> = toFormControl
) {
    while (array.length) {
        array.removeAt(0);
    }
    values
        .map(toSubControl)
        .forEach(function(control) {
            array.push(control);
        });
    return array;
}
```

Where the following functions can create the new child `AbstractControl`s.

```
// When the child controls should be FormControl
function toFormControl<T>(value: T) {
    return new FormControl(value)
}

// When the child controls should be FormGroup
function toFormGroup<T>(item: T) {
    const fields = Object.entries(item).reduce(function(hash, [key, value]) {
        hash[key] = new FormControl(value);
        return hash;
    }, {});
    return new FormGroup(fields);
}

// When the child controls should be FormArray of FormControls
function toFormArray<T>(values: T) {
    const fields = values.map(value => new FormControl(value));
    return new FormGroup(fields);
}
```

Comment: I improve (I hope) your function in a new answer

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your functions

```
getFormArray<T>(elements: T[]): FormArray {
    return new FormArray(
      elements.map((x: T) => {
        const obj = new FormGroup({});
        Object.keys(x).forEach(k => {
          obj.addControl(k, new FormControl(x[k]));
        });
        return obj;
      })
    );
  }

//the use, e.g.

this.formArray = this.getFormArray<any>([
  { id: 1, name: "Bob" },
  { id: 2, name: "Peter" }
]);
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvvhwd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I wanted to edit the FormArray in-place. But this is nice if you don't have that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an empty formArray and then add the controls and then set the value,

```js
const arr = new FormArray([]);

const a = new FormControl('a', []);
const b = new FormControl('b', []);
const c = new FormControl('c', []);

arr.push(a);
arr.push(b);
arr.push(c);

console.log(arr.value);   // ["a", "b", "c"] 
// arr.setValue([0]);

console.log(arr) 
arr.controls[0].setValue('xxx')

console.log(arr.value);   // "xxx", "b", "c"
```

Comment: How do I make a function out of this to solve problems in my app?